# Xdebug logging connection errors when it's not supposed to be running

Tags: wordpress, docker, xdebug, vscode-debugger, lando

WordPress site built using a Lando development environment.

Debugging in WordPress is enabled, as is debugging to a log file.

In VS Code I have the following `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "log": false,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/app/": "${workspaceFolder}/"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my `php.ini`:

```ini
; Xdebug
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 256
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
xdebug.collect_params = 0
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = ${LANDO_HOST_IP}

; Remote settings
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_host = ${LANDO_HOST_IP}
```

When I start debugging in VS Code everything works as expected.

When debugging isn't active in VS Code (i.e. the green triangle hasn't been clicked)... I get lots of the following error in my WordPress debug log:

> Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 172.20.0.1:9003 (from HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR HTTP header), 192.168.1.18:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

Is there a way to prevent Xdebug constantly trying to connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent Xdebug constantly trying to connect?

Yes, don't tell it to connect if you don't want it to connect. You have set `xdebug.start_with_request=yes`, which means that Xdebug will do as asked, and try to make a connection. If it can't, you'll get a warning.

FWIW, the `xdebug.remote_*` settings do nothing in Xdebug 3.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion in combination with having the debugging icon disabled in Firefox (the one in the URL bar) did the trick.